# Can you use Keep-Alive with a CONNECT request with an HTTP proxy?

Tags: http, https, proxy, http-proxy

I know that with HTTP/1.1 proxies, it's possible to use Keep-Alive to keep a persistent connection with the proxy and from the proxy to the remote server, but I'm curious if/how that would work with an HTTPS connection. I know that to do this, the browser sends a CONNECT request to the proxy to establish a connection then begins communicating using HTTPS. I'm curious if it's possible to use Keep-Alive with HTTPS through an http proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, CONNECT is always keep-alive.

In HTTP, “persistent connection” means a connection that persists after one request-response pair. But CONNECT establishes a *tunnel through* the proxy. The proxy cannot even see the requests and responses that are sent over this tunnel (because they are encrypted). So there is no way for this tunnel to *not* be persistent.

Of course, if the server (the target of CONNECT) decides to close the connection, then the tunnel is destroyed, too. So the server must support persistent connections (just as with a regular, non-TLS proxy).

Comment: When the client and remote are in TLS communication status, If the remote server close the connection, then will proxy server keep the proxy-connection and is it possible to reuse it as a normal HTTP connection?

Comment: @osexp2003 I think the answer is no, and I think [RFC 7231 § 4.3.6](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.6) agrees. There’s just no general way for a proxy to signal such a condition to the client.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov thank you. got it. Seems any 'upgradable' request such as CONNECT and WebSocket will cause proxy server loose control of the connection so it can not determine when to reuse the proxy connection.